# Display html pages containing css, jpg using Bottle

Tags: python, html, css, bottle

I have around 100 journal articles. Each journal article is represented as an HTML page. A journal's HTML page, its css file and the figures that are part of the journal are located within its folder. In other words, each html file refers to it's own css file and corresponding image files. And I have created the following folder structure ( | represents a folder, -- represents a file):

`-- app.py
  |views
   -- Disp_Res.tpl
   -- UI.tpl
  |static
     |articles
        |PMC45677
         --PMC45677.html
         --jats-preview.css
         --fig1_45677.jpg
         --fig2_45677.jpg
        |PMC23456
         --PMC23456.html
         --jats-preview.css
         --fig1_23456.jpg
         --fig2_23456.jpg`

I have the following code within my app.py

```
@app.get('/articles/<pmc:re:PMC[0-9]*>')
def html_article(pmc):    
    global pmcno
    pmcno = pmc; 
    pmc_article = pmcno + ".html"; print pmc_article        
    rootdir = os.path.join('static/articles', pmcno) #'static/articles/{pmcno}'
    print "html_article", rootdir # This statement displays the right dir
    return static_file(pmc_article, root=rootdir)


@app.get('/<filename:re:.*\.css>')
def stylesheets(filename):
    rootdir = os.path.join('static/articles', pmcno)
    print "stylesheets", rootdir # This statement does NOT display
    return static_file(filename, root=rootdir)


@app.get('/<filename:re:.*\.(jpg|png|gif|ico)>')
def images(filename):
    rootdir = os.path.join('static/articles', pmcno)
    print "images", rootdir # This statement does NOT display
    return static_file(filename, root=rootdir)
```

And needless to say this doesn't work. When I run app.py, it just gives me the error: 
"Sorry, the requested URL 'http://localhost:8080/articles/PMC45677' caused an error:
File does not exist."

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Or do you have a better idea of achieving what I am aiming at? Please do let me know. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because Bottle doesn't know what /articles/ is ?

Try to add this in top of your code :

```
@app.route('/articles/<filepath:path>')
def file_stac(filepath):
  return static_file(filepath,root="./articles")
```